# Angular2-jwt: intercept requested api route

Tags: angular, angular2-jwt

I'm implementing a jwt refresh mechanism. I'm using [auth0/angular2-jwt](https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt) with Angular 7. When I'm accessing a protected route, I'm sending a request to /api/v1/protected with my `access_token` in the Authorization header. When I need to refresh the jwt token, I've got to send a request to /api/v1/auth/refresh with my `refresh_token` in the Authorization header. 
What I can't figure out is how to select which token I'll send based on the api route.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { JwtModule, JWT_OPTIONS } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { TokenService } from './services/token.service';

export function jwtOptionsFactory(tokenService) {
  return {
    tokenGetter: () => {
      return tokenService.getAsyncToken();
    },
      whitelistedDomains: [
        'localhost',
        'localhost:80',
        'localhost:443',
        'localhost:4200', 
      ],
      blacklistedRoutes: [],
      throwNoTokenError: false,

  }
}
...
@NgModule({
...
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
    JwtModule.forRoot({
      jwtOptionsProvider: {
        provide: JWT_OPTIONS,
        useFactory: jwtOptionsFactory,
        deps: [TokenService]
      }
    }),

  ],
...
})
```

**token.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TokenService {

  constructor() { }

  getAsyncToken(){
    // This is the part in question
    if (route=='/api/v1/auth/refresh') {
       return localStorage.getItem('refresh_token');
    } 
    return localStorage.getItem('access_token');

  }


}
```

My plan B is to blacklist the refresh route in angulat-jwt and write a custom interceptor. 
But I'd like to know if there's something I messed. Is this possible to intercept the api call (check the api route) in my token service?

Comment: Hope this might give you the right direction https://itnext.io/angular-tutorial-implement-refresh-token-with-httpinterceptor-bfa27b966f57

Comment: @Suryan Thanks for the link. Basically an interceptor will do the same thing as JwtModule. I'm thinking, why am I using JwtModule, if I still have to write a custom interceptor? :)